# saving a video that has background subtraction applied to it in python 3.5 using open cv

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried looking for the answer to my question but I have not really found an answer. I am wondering how to save a video file in python 3.5 that has background subtraction applied to it and in addition curious as to where the output file is supposed to be saved to?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On StackOverflow, it's customary to upvote answers you find helpful (that's the little upwards pointing triangle next to the answer). Also, if it's an answer to your question and you deem it the best one, there's a little checkmark that let's you "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

tried out this code in anaconda 3.5 with opencv 3.1 works just fine to subtract background from a video file and then saving it to an output file

```
import cv2
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

capture = cv2.VideoCapture('people-walking.mp4')
size = (int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"DIB ")
video = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 30,size)
fgbg= cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while True:
    ret, img = capture.read()
    if ret==True:
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(img)
        video.write(fgmask)
        cv2.imshow('forehead',fgmask)

    if(cv2.waitKey(27)!=-1):
        break

capture.release()
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: **TypeError: Required argument 'c4' (pos 4) not found.** If I change `DIB` to `XVID` no error occurs, but the saved video doesn't play.

Comment: This code worked for me when used along with the above mentioned versions.

Comment: Look at my solution. I faced similar problem. It may solve your problem. @AlaaM.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was facing a problem. Then added `isColor=False` argument to the `VideoWriter`. It solved the issue.

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
out = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480), isColor=False)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,180)

        outmask = out.apply(frame)
        output.write(outmask)

        cv2.imshow('original', frame)
        cv2.imshow('Motion Tracker', outmask)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        break


output.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```